# PHP API: Call a Post API with multiple parameters

Tags: php, api

I'm new to making API. I want to know, how to call a post API with multiple parameters? I know get API can be called with multiple parameters but is there any way to call a POST API like that?
here is my code:

*api.php* :

```
if ($action == 'user_assign_machine') {
    $id = $PARAMS['id'];
    $user_Id = $PARAMS['user_Id'];
    $res = HR::userAssignMachine($user_Id,$id);
    echo json_encode($res);
```

*code-api.php* :

```
public static function userAssignMachine($userid,$machineid) {
  $message_to_admin = "Hi Admin! User $user_Id wants to assign machine $machineid";
  return $message_to_admin;  
}
```

Now I want to call this API through a link, i.e. passing all the parameters in the API URL link. plz help me out.
thanks

Comment: It's very difficult to work out what your question is. The code you've posted doesn't seem to match what you're asking either

Comment: i want to call a post api by passing required parameters in the url. example: api url : _http://foo.com/api.php?action=user_assign_machine&userid=100&machineid=200_ i know its possible in get but how to do that in post method

Answer (score 0):

for post requests from PHP, you could use curl

```
public static function userAssignMachine($userid,$machineid,$url) {
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'userid' => $userid,
        'machineid' => $machineid
    )
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
}
```

Comment: so in this way, if we want to put a link in the msg sent to the admin i.e., `$message_to_admin = "Hi Admin! User $user_Id wants to assign machine $machineid <$resp|Approve>";` this will work to call the api with parameters?

Comment: If you want to post the message to admin, you can add it as a field in the post data . CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'userid' => $userid,
        'machineid' => $machineid, 'message_to_admin'=>"Hi Admin! User ".$user_Id." wants to assign machine ".$machineid." <".$resp."|Approve>"
    )

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl send the multiple data using post

This is the best way for creating apis

```
$ch = curl_init();
$curlConfig = array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => "http://www.example.com/yourscript.php",
    CURLOPT_POST           => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => array(
        'field1' => 'some date',
        'field2' => 'some other data',
    )
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlConfig);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// result sent by the remote server is in $result
```

[curl reference](https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-curl)